# Compare an element of a list against all other elements

Tags: list, scala, scala-collections

Say I have a Scala list,

```
val list : List[Set[Int]] = List(set1, set2, set3, set4)
```

where each element of my list is a set of integers.

I'm looking for an elegant way to create a list where each element of my list is compared against *all* others.  For example, I might want to generate a list where each element (set) contains only elements not contained in any other element of the list.

*e.g.* I have some function:

```
def f(element : Set[Int], rest_of_list : List[Set[Int]]) : Set[Int]
```

and I want to do something similar to `list.map(f(_, rest_of_list))` without having to construct `rest_of_list` for each element.  The only way I can think of doing it right now is to use `slice`, which makes it very ugly and inefficient, imo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `diff` instead of `slice`:

```
 list.map(set => set diff (list diff List(set)).flatten.toSet)
 //Alternative with filterNot
 list.map(set => set.filterNot((list diff List(set)).flatten.contains))
```

`diff` works here since it only removes one instance of the element, and `Set[Int]` has a nice `equals` method:

```
List(Set(1), Set(1, 2)) diff List(Set(1)) //List(Set(1, 2))
List(Set(1), Set(1)) diff List(Set(1)) //List(Set(1))
```

So, to this maps a set to the list of all other sets in the list:

```
val setWithOthers = list.map(set => set -> (list diff List(set)))
val setWithOthers = (list, list.map(list diff List(_))).zipped.toList //equivalent, less efficient
```

So if you wanted to map your function `f` across elements of `list`, you could do:

```
setsWithOthers.map { case(set, others) => f(set, others) }
setsWithOthers.map(kvp => f(kvp._1, kvp._2))
setsWithOthers.map((f _).tupled)
```

You could also create the full multiset which keeps track of how many times each element appears.  Then, in each iteration of the loop, you can "subtract" a set from the full multiset:

```
val multiset = list.flatten.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)
```

Comment: That's orders of magnitude prettier than using slices, but it still isn't what I was hoping for.  (My disappointment is aimed at scala, not your answer)

Comment: hehe you updated your answer with a nicer version of what I was thinking.  The map approach is the answer I'm accepting.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is as elegant as you want but a more general way that you can replace 'f' with anything:

```
val list = List(Set(1,2,3,4),Set(1,2),Set(1,3))

list.map(e => f(e,list.filterNot(_==e)))
//res0: List[Set[Int]] = List(Set(4), Set(), Set())

def f(element : Set[Int], rest_of_list : List[Set[Int]]) : Set[Int] = {
  (element.toList diff rest_of_list.flatten.toList).toSet
}
```